# 2 buttons next to each other with different div

Tags: html, css

I want to put the View button on left and the add button on right, but next to each other. The 2 buttons are in different divs. How can I do this?

### Demo

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group" id="divNewNotificationsRole-admin">
    <button id="role-admin" type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">View</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a></li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="rolecontainer" class="container">
  <div id="addContainer" align="right">
    <button type="button" name="add" id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_data_Modal" class="btn btn-warning">Add</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add float: right to #rolecontainer.

Comment: use bootstrap, row and col, etc

Comment: Your structure is quite wrong. Since you are using `Bootstrap` you can use `row` `column` structure. Or you can try `display: flex`  CSS property to the parent of the 2 buttons.

Comment: @חייםפרידמן because the OP is already using bootstrap ;) .. I am not suggesting to use a *new* library

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh, I didn't notice...

Comment: It's weird way to use BS _container_ for every button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to add a `float: left;` to the first button container.

```css
.btn-group {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">

  <div class="btn-group" id="divNewNotificationsRole-admin">
    <button id="role-admin" type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">View</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a></li>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="rolecontainer" class="container">
    <div id="addContainer" align="right">
      <button type="button" name="add" id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_data_Modal" class="btn btn-warning">Add</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: you should include bootstrap to see the real effect of this

Comment: Of course, you're right. I always use JSFiddle to edit codesnippets, so I forgot to include Bootstrap again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put both buttons inside the same div, and use bootstrap classes "left" and "right":

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-group" id="divNewNotificationsRole-admin">
    
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a></li>
      <li><a id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a></li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="rolecontainer" class="container">
    <button id="role-admin" type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split left" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">View</button>
  
    <button type="button" name="add" id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_data_Modal" class="btn btn-warning right">Add</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap row and column classes to avoid various resolution issues.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<div class="container">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-1 clo-lg-1">
        <div class="btn-group" id="divNewNotificationsRole-admin">
            <button id="role-admin" type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                View</button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a id="dropdown1" class="dropdown-item" href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a id="dropdown2" class="dropdown-item" href="#">2</a></li>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-1 clo-lg-1">
        <div id="rolecontainer">
            <div id="addContainer">  
                <button type="button" name="add" id="add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_data_Modal" class="btn btn-warning">Add</button>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better practice for this is to CSS both parent divs containing the button with

```
.div1, .div2 {
display: inline-block;
}
```

Having this will put them inline.